# Magento product uploading from Orddermotion ERP

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have created a extension which is able to upload product from ordermotion ERP to Magento.So we are using OrderMotion API through which we are getting the products information and updating into Magento one by one. But after uploading 14000 thousand products from ordermotion to Magento I got following erro into my log file:-

::- Base table or view not exist:- catalog_category_product_index_tmp

I checked database , so there is no any table with this name. As per my understanding Magento create this table during indexing but why I am getting this error when I am updating the product.

Can anyone tell me why this is coming?

Note :- Because we are getting product information one by one from order motion , so it is taking 6-7 hours for updating the products.

Magento version:- 1.13.2 Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

You should only only update any changes, and what product information, you should use sync from ordermotion only on some information, description you should not, it looks like your error has to do with the category and how OMX uses categories and attributes versus magento. New tables in the db need to be created.